# Summaryfields Extension - 'Largest Contribution' includes Test contributions

Tags: summaryfields

Summary Fields v. 4.0.2
CiviCRM v. 5.16.3
Drupal 7

Our solution is clear - remove the test transactions. Also, end users won't have any test contributions so it won't be a problem for reporting for them.

However, Summary Fields seem to be including contributions that are marked as test - for instance, test event registrations. On the contribution tab, they are clearly marked as "Financial Type (test)".

Comment: If you are mostly reporting a problem it may be worth adding as an Issue on the extension github - it may not cause anything to be done but at least the maintainers of the extension will know about it

Comment: Can do - I wasn't sure if I misconfigured or if its a problem, seems like it may be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

The developers fixed it in the master branch, if anyone comes across this: https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.sumfields/issues/63